# Unable to Install Samba after uninstalling?

Tags: linux, debian, samba, reinstall

I have removed samba using :

```
apt-get --purge remove samba
```

and then Manually removed the smb.conf using `rm *.*` after going to the Samba directory.

Now While I trying to install Samba again I am getting the following error:

```
Starting Samba daemons: nmbd/usr/sbin/nmbd: /usr/local/lib/libldap_r-2.4.so.2: no version information available (required by /usr/sbin/nmbd)
/usr/sbin/nmbd: /usr/local/lib/liblber-2.4.so.2: no version information available (required by /usr/sbin/nmbd)
 failed!
```

I am unable understand why this is happening. Please help

**Edit:**
After trying `ps aux | grep samba` getting the follwing response:

```
root     25793  0.0  0.0   3088   716 pts/0    R+   09:17   0:00 grep samba
```

Have no idea what to do with this?

**Edit@Matthew**

Now Have the follwoing error:
Processing triggers for man-db ...

```
Setting up samba-common (2:3.2.5-4lenny11) ...
Not replacing deleted config file /etc/samba/smb.conf
chmod: cannot access `/etc/samba/smb.conf': No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing samba-common (--configure):
 subprocess post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of samba:
 samba depends on samba-common (= 2:3.2.5-4lenny11); however:
  Package samba-common is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing samba (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 samba-common
 samba
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have already removed smb.cnf file

Comment: In your question above, the output of the `ps aux | grep samba` command showed you one result, and that was the `grep samba` command you ran. If samba was running, you'd have another result listed there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it's because you uninstalled samba only and wiped out the config file so something stayed installed and without configuration.

I think there are ways to repair, but I would try to reinstall on a "clean" base doing:

```
sudo dpkg -P samba samba-common smbclient
sudo rm -f /etc/rc*.d/*samba /etc/init.d/samba
```

before anything and reinstall with `sudo apt-get install samba`

Answer (score 3):

You have a incompatible shared library in /usr/local.  That was installed separately, *not* as part of a Debian package (Debian packages are [not allowed](http://www.debian.org/doc/maint-guide/ch-modify.en.html#s-destdir) to install to /usr/local).  You should remove it, and any other related shared libraries in /usr/local, uninstall all SAMBA packages, then reinstall

Note that the grep result means no process containing "samba" is executing.  Only the grep is running; I know this looks a little confusing.

EDIT:

Okay, try:

```
sudo rm /usr/local/lib/libldap_r-2.4.so.2
```

This removes a shared library that was separately installed to /usr/local.  You may have others there, but you removing the wrong ones could break your system.

```
sudo apt-get remove samba samba-common smbclient swat samba-doc smbfs libpam-smbpass libsmbclient libsmbclient-dev winbind
```

This removes all samba-related packages.

Now, reinstall what you need.  E.g.:

```
sudo apt-get install samba
```

EDIT 2:

Nikolaidis is right.  Manually removing all the SAMBA config files was a mistake.  Do:

```
sudo cp /usr/share/samba/smb.conf /etc/samba/smb.conf
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Comment: Could you please provide the commands , I am complete newbie in Linux

Comment: Deleting everything is not usually considered as good idea !
Try dpkg --configure -a to repair the .deb database and afterwards retry. Propably a force flag is what you need.

Answer (score 1):

try `ps aux | grep samba`. Did you stop the previous running instance of samba ?

Comment: No, I did not stop that and hope there might be some problem. Though I did stop it immedeately after few seconds

Comment: Edited the Question after getting the response of the command

Answer (score 1):

Try

`ps aux | grep smbd`

**The process names you should expect to find when running Samba are `smbd` and `nmbd`, not `samba`**.

You did run `apt-get --purge remove samba` to get rid of your previous Samba installation. *But you did not tell which command you used to re-install Samba.* So I can only guess where your real problem comes from, and what the possible solution is.

Should you want to install it from your official Debian software repositories, then use the following sequence:

1. `apt-get update` (This brings your system's local knowledge about all currently available software packages up to date. This is important!)
2. `apt-get install  samba smbclient` (This does not only install Samba and the Samba client utils, but it also brings all *'dependencies'* up to date.)

If this does not help, then run

- `dpkg --configure -a` (This will try to repair a damaged SW package database.)

and repeat the `apt-get install ...` command. If this did not help, then run

- `dpkg --force-confmiss --configure samba` (This will install missing config files)

and repeat the `apt-get install ...` command.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed my issue by running the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge samba-common
sudo apt-get remove --purge samba
sudo apt-get install samba
```